# Выборка значений по первым буквам в теге <input>

Tags: angular

Реализовал возможность выбора значения для поля "клиент" в таблице "визиты"

```
  <input type = "text" class="form-control" id="field_client" name="client" [(ngModel)]="visit.clientId" list="clientnames" >
                <datalist id = "clientnames">
                    <option [ngValue]="null"></option>
                    <option [ngValue]="clientOption.id" *ngFor="let clientOption of clients; trackBy: trackClientById">{{clientOption.name}}</option>
                </datalist>
```

При вводе начинаю предлагаться подходящие значения. Но при попытке сохранить получаю ошибку о несоответствии типов. Обнаружил, что на сервер передаётся clientOption.name вместо clientOption.id.

Где ошибка?

Comment: `ngValue` - для объектов, для примитивных типов используйте `[value]="clientOption.id" || value="{{ clientOption.id }}"`

Comment: Спасибо, работает! Есть правда один странный эффект: при начале ввода  в выпадающем  списке  появляется черта, делящая список на две части. При этом в обеих частях есть одни и те же значения. Кол-во значений в верхнем списке может быть разным.  Если выбрать значение из верхней части, то в поле появляется строковое значение и при попытке сохранить возникает та же ошибка. При выборе значения из нижней  части в поле появляется числовое значение id и всё сохраняется.

Comment: к сожалению тут не могу вам ответить не зная все бизнес логики ;)